# SFMC JB Custom Activity | Extract values from DE directly into custom activity config?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, custom-activity

I have a simple question that needs a definitive answer.

I've created a DE with 3 fields. SubscriberKey, FirstName, LastName

I want to bring these fields into my config.json and post them to my endpoint.

```
"arguments": {
"execute": {
  "inArguments": [
      {"subscriberKey": "{{SubscriberKey}}"},
      {"firstName": "{{SubscriberKey.Attribute.DEname.FirstName}}"},
      {"lastName": "{{SubscriberKey.Attribute.DEname.LastName}}"}
],
  "outArguments": [],
  "url": "Some endpoint",
  "verb": "POST",
  "body": "",
  "header": "",
  "format": "json",
  "useJwt": true,
  "timeout": 1000
}
},
```

docs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm

Everywhere I look including the above documentation it mentions the need to create a relationship with a field in Contact Builder. Is this a necessary step? Is it not possible to reference DE values directly and bring them into a custom activity config without creating this relationship?

With the above example, I am hitting the endpoint but the fields are not visible. I have not created a data relationship with contact builder but why is this a necessary step?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values always taken from this same data extension, or are they taken from the entry data?

Comment: Hi @Macca - values will always be retrieved from this DE. I am using this DE as the entry source for this journey.

Comment: For instance, in AMPscript you can easily reference values in your DE by declaring a variable in your email HTML. I want similar functionality for this activity, however, don't understand the need to create a data relationship in contact builder when I am just required to bring values directly from the DE being used for the journey.

Comment: Yes. You'd need to define the relationship between your Data Extension and the Contact Model using Contact Builder's Data Designer. There could be multiple ways in which that data extension might be relatable to your Contact, so in order to allow Journey Builder to understand how to lookup values in that table, you need to provide the fully qualified path in order to successfully data bind. You don't actually need to do this for the SubscriberKey, just use "{{Contact.Key}}".

Comment: @Macca thank you, so what your saying is that since SubscriberKey is already defined in my org I can simply use it as the contact key?

Comment: To elaborate, the test DE I am using states that SubscriberKey relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key as the data relationship.

Comment: Yes. The Contact Key's not dependent on doing any linking in Contact Builder. All records entering a Journey must come from a Sendable Data Extension where the relationship between the table and the contact model is already defined by the sendable field of the DE.

Comment: @Macca - Thank you very much this has been extremely helpful. I am now able to retrieve SubscriberKey in my POST. - That being said I am still unable to retrieve FirstName and LastName from my DE. Is this the correct syntax? "lastName": "{{Contact.Attribute.TestActivitySource.LastName}}"

Comment: @Macca, also, if you'd like please feel free to answer this question and I'd be happy to mark it as correct for this thread. - Again, really appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to define the relationship between your Data Extension and the Contact Model using Contact Builder's Data Designer. There could be multiple ways in which that data extension might be relatable to your Contact, so in order to allow Journey Builder to understand how to lookup values in that table, you need to provide the fully qualified path in order to successfully data bind. You don't actually need to do this for the SubscriberKey, just use "{{Contact.Key}}".

Data binding syntax is detailed on [the page you quoted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) in your question. For Contact Model data binding, you use the following syntax - Contact.Attribute.[FullyQualifiedAttributeName]. The actual fully qualified path would vary depending on how you've configured your attribute groups and relationships in Contact Builder. To illustrate, assuming you have a Data Extension called "MyCustomers" linked directly to your contact data in Contact Builder similar to that below:

[image]

Assuming this data model and your requirement to get back ContactKey, FirstName and LastName as InArguments on execute, your inArguments definition passed back using Postmonger on saving the activity would look like this:

```
[{
  "SubscriberKey": "{{Contact.Key}}"
}, {
  "FirstName": "{{Contact.Attribute.MyCustomers.FirstName}}"
}, {
  "LastName": "{{Contact.Attribute.MyCustomers.LastName}}"
}]
```

Note that where there are any spaces in the fully qualified path, you'll need to place the elements of the path in quotes, eg: {{Contact.Attribute.\"My Customers\".\"Last Name\"}}.

Comment: thank you very much for this comprehensive answer. It is much appreciated and does clear some things up. There is one last thing that I am wondering. With the info you have provided I have successfully posted the subscriberKey using {{Contact.Key}} and this is without creating a data relationship in contact builder. How is it possible that I am able to POST subscriberKey from my DE when I have not yet binded my data to an attribute group?

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to fully understand is why I need to link my DE to contact builder when the data in my DE is static and not dependent on the contact model. When records pass over my activity it would be ideal to simply access data in this static DE that I'm using for the entry source e.g. (first name and last name) without having to create a data relationship.

Comment: In my example above I have a table called "MyCustomers". It could have a bunch of fields in it and any one of them could relate back to the ContactKey that's running through the Journey Builder Interaction. My example above uses a field called "SubscriberKey", so the relationship's pretty obvious to you or I, but how would Journey Builder know that it can get the FirstName and LastName inArgs for the Contact based on ContactKey=SubscriberKey?

Comment: Adding "MyCustomers" to the Data Designer and defining the relationship between the Contact and the table to be Contact.ContactKey = MyCustomers.SubscriberKey allows Journey Builder to bind your inArgs to the Contact.

Comment: Instead of linking in contact builder you also have access to static fields from your entry source DE using {{Event.Entry-event-key.YOUR_FIELD}}. Any event fields do not require a relationship in contact builder because they are a cache of the entire row that was injected into the journey, from the time it was injected. If you are not expecting these fields to be updated between the journey entry and this activity, I would recommend this as it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks. That's true, @Tyler. But the OP stated in response to my first comment that the fields were not available in the entry data. As an aside, getting the EventDefinitionKey on the fly in your Custom Activity's probably more difficult and fraught with issues like copying of the journey or reversioning breaking the data binding. Here, we're hard-coding the inArgs.

Comment: Sorry that was not how I read it -> “it would be ideal to simply access data in this static de that I’m using for the entry source”  and 2 days ago “I am using this DE as the entry source for my journey”. Please let me know if I’m totally missing something but if not this sounds like exactly what OP is asking for.

Comment: I guess I see what you mean, @Tyler. If you were only ever using this custom activity in this Journey and were never going to change or update the entry audience in any way or re-version the Journey, I guess hard coding the EventDefinitionKey might be easier.

Comment: No need to hardcode. You can trigger/use the ‘requestTriggerEventDefinition’ postmonger event to dynamically pull this in when configuring the activity. Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/using-postmonger.htm

Comment: Yes. You could, @Tyler, and then watch your data binding break when you change the entry source in any way, reversion your journey or copy the Journey. I'm not sure this is easier.

Comment: Looks like I opened the right can of worms. All of this is very helpful, @Tyler you are correct. My DE is static as I am testing custom activity functionality and learning the landscape. I think I may go the route of using the event key. - That being said, let's say my DE is refreshed everyday with an automation and gets (x) amount of new rows per day. I am expecting new records to pass over my custom activity on each refresh based on a set schedule. Will the event key method still be viable? I hope yes since the fields are already specified in my config at this point.

Comment: To set the data binding in the way @Tyler's suggesting, you'd do it as part of your Postmonger's Save event handler, rather than placing them in your config.json as they'd no longer be static. Each time your UI loads, you'd inspect the current eventDefinitionKey for the Journey and set the inArgs dynamically. Keep in mind that the eventDefinitionKey for a Data Extension entry source jumps around and isn't constant, even if the Data Extension used is the same.

Comment: Your activity only gets to know of changes to the eventDefinitionKey when its UI is loaded or potentially, when the validate route is hit as the user attempts to activate the Journey. It's very easy for your activity's data bindings in your inArgs to become invalid. This happens if you copy the journey, re-version it or change the event entry source in any way. You'd need to do some form of checks when the validate route's hit in order to prevent the journey being activated when your inArgs no longer match the current eventDefinitionKey.

Comment: @Macca these are some interesting pitfalls. It seems simple enough to add some validation on a specific key, however, I did not know the key would be variable. Does it revert back to the specified key after the activity has hit all of its routes? I can deal with the key changing if the journey is re-versioned or copied. My concern is that the key will change every time new rows are added to the entry source DE. I guess I'm at a loss to why it is possible to reference subscriberKey and even email address  (interactionDefault) but not easily access and POST other fields in the same entry source.

Comment: No. The eventDefinitionKey doesn't change unless the Journey's changed in the ways mentioned.

Comment: I have managed to log the eventdefinition key to my console from the DE. Really just looking for information on how to bind the data (inArgs) in my save event handler using this key, and then use that dynamic data from the DE for a POST.

Comment: Please disregard the above, I've managed to do exactly what I wanted to do by passing the eventDefinitionModel into my save function and defining my inArgs with syntax that looks a bit like this - var firstName = "{{Event." + [deEventKey] + ".FirstName}}" - Where deEventKey is the EventDefinitionKey being pulled from the eventDefinitionModel. Thank you again guys, this has been extremely helpful. You have filled holes that the documentation left out.